# Keep text inside rectangle even on zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am displaying circle as markers. Each circle has a value which will generally be between 0 and 200 (it can have 2 decimals).

I am trying to display the circle and a label containing the value next to it inside a rectangle.

**CODE**

```
data.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "station")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return (d.coordinates.x + 5000) / 450;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return (-d.coordinates.y + 170000) / 450;
    })
    .style("stroke-width", .5)
    .style("cursor", "pointer")
    .style("fill", "red");

    //Box containing the station label
data.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "stationBox")
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return 10 + 4 * d.value.toString().length;
    })
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return ((d.coordinates.x + 5000) / 450);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return ((-d.coordinates.y + 170000) / 450 - 10);
    })
    .attr("fill", "lemonchiffon")
    .style("cursor", "pointer");

//Station label
data.append("text")
    .attr("class", "stationLabel")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return ((d.coordinates.x + 5000) / 450 + 2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return ((-d.coordinates.y + 170000) / 450 - 2);
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "right")
    .style("font-size", "0.7em")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    })
    .style("cursor", "pointer");
```

This will display this [image: Circle with label] and this looks ok.

My main problem is that I can zoom in/out my map. I need the text to stay inside the rectangle + they need to be smaller be zoomed in.

I tried to change the `font-size` of the text and the `width` of the rectangle but how can I choose the new values ?

**EDIT**

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sed403n5/). You can see that when you zoom in, the text is getting bigger and the rectangle too. I need them to stay small and the text need to stay inside the rectangle

Comment: need a working example in a fiddle.

Comment: @Cyril Updated question